# PHP | MySQL Разобрать масив и сохранить в БД

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Есть масив который хочу разобрать и записать в новую БД. Все что я пробовал не дало ожидаемого результата, а подозрение , что это намного проще чем я думаю, у меня есть.

```
 Array ( 
    [0] => ( 
    [ID] => 959
    [datakey] => 606
    [key] => keyname1
    [value] => valuename1
    [group] => tst
        )
    [1] => ( 
    [ID] => 960
    [datakey] => 606
    [key] => keyname2
    [value] => valuename2 
    [group] => tst
        )
    [2] => ( 
    [ID] => 961 
    [datakey] => 606
    [key] => keyname3
    [value] => valuename3
    [group] => tst2
        )
    [3] => ( 
    [ID] => 962 
    [datakey] => 607
    [key] => keyname1
    [value] => valuename1
    [group] => tst 
        )
    )
```

....

Нужно сохранить это в базу данных таким образом

```
id  |  datakey   |   tst (group)              | tst2  (group)          | ...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  606       | keyname1 -> valuename1,      keyname3 -> valuename3 ...
                   keyname2 -> valuename2 ...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  607       |  keyname1 -> valuename1,   |  ...
```

Comment: Уточните как разбираете и добавляете данные?

Comment: Не проще в бд создать только одно поле tst в котором разместить массив в формате JSON. Или для каждого ключа массива создать поле и нормально разместить данные из массива в поля  [ID_array]  [datakey]  [key]  [value] [group]

Answer (score 0):

Сначала сформируем новый массив с данными:

```php
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $array) {
    $content = $result[$array['datakey']][$array['group']];
    $value = implode(' ', [$array['key'], '->', $array['value']]);

    $result[$array['datakey']][$array['group']] = empty($content) ? $value : $content . ', ' . $value;
}
```

И после этого добавим новые строки в таблицу в БД:

```php
foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
    $tstValue = $row['tst'] ?? '';
    $tst2Value = $row['tst2'] ?? '';

    // Формируем SQL-запрос на вставку данных
    $query = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO `table` SET `datakey` = $key, `tst` = '{$tstValue}', `tst2` = '{$tst2Value}';
SQL;

    // И здесь выполняем этот запрос
    mysqli_query($link, $query);
}
```

**[!]** Второй цикл представлен только в качестве примера, разумеется, вы должны по возможности добавлять данные одним запросом, а не в цикле, и проверять входящие значения, перед вставкой в БД.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая прекрасная библиотека для работы с MySQL: https://github.com/Vasiliy-Makogon/Database . Посмотрите документацию, может упростить решение вашей задачи.

Comment: Зачем рекомендовать поделку 2-х летней давности, написанной на php 5.3?